# Image Loading from URL in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm currently working on a project using Compose Multiplatform project, and looking for ways to handle image loading from a URL. However, since Coil isn't supported, I haven't found a solution.

I've come across a manual Ktor implementation that converts bitmaps, but it lacks caching support and other implementation details(e.g. loading, error states).

Has anyone integrated image loading using a library or found other alternatives for Compose Multiplatform?

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/Kamel-Media/Kamel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) 3.0.0-alpha06 has multiplatform support

Basic configuration below, typically `shared/build.gradle.kts`:

```
    kotlin {
        // targets configuration
        
        sourceSets {
            commonMain.dependencies {
                implementation("io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose:3.0.0-alpha06")
                implementation("io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor:3.0.0-alpha06")
            }
            androidMain.dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:2.3.7")
            }
            iosMain.dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.7")
            }
        }
    }
```

IMPORTANT: To load images from a network URL in Coil 3.0 you'll need to import a separate artifact for each source set.

Basic usage of `AsyncImage`:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = "https://example.com/image.jpg", // replace with working URL 
    contentDescription = null
)
```

For more advanced usage over loading and error use [SubcomposeAsyncImage](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#subcomposeasyncimage)

If you already using coil 2.x, then check [guide how to upgrade to coil 3.x](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/upgrading_to_coil3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Kamel** can load images from URLs: https://github.com/Kamel-Media/Kamel

Gradle dependencies:

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("media.kamel:kamel-image:x.x.x")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:y.y.y") 
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
KamelImage(
    resource = asyncPainterResource(data = "https://example.com/image.jpg"),
    contentDescription = "description"
)
```